# Appropriate statistical test: 2 groups, 2 measures, one measure in common

Tags: mixed-model, anova, f-test

Group 1 does measure A and measure B. Group 2 does measure A and measure C. A, B, and C are all on the same scale (say 1-100). What's the appropriate test if I want to compare means on A, B, and C?

I'm a bit confused what kind of ANOVA it should be. If I wanted to compare A and B, it would be within-groups ANOVA. If I wanted to compare B and C, it would be between-groups ANOVA. But, comparing A, B, and C all together, it involves both. Does this call for a Mixed-Factorial ANOVA?

Comment: Could you explain what "does measure A" mean and how "A," "B," and "C" might be related?

Comment: You can probably only do anything with A. For instance, your groups might be males vs. females, measure A might be height, B is "number of apples owned" and C "number of oranges owned". We don't want to compare apples and oranges. Or, put differently, if you want to compare B and C, you need some additional information beyond "we measured group 1 on B and group 2 on C".

Comment: So, to elaborate, "A, B, and C" are 3 versions of a decision-making task. Say the choice is "do or don't do" activity A, B, or C. We want to compare how many times people choose to do the activity (A, B, C) vs don't do it, Thus, it's not "apples to oranges"--for all 3 tasks, they make the same number of choices and get a total count of how many times they chose to do it (say you chose 70 out of 100 times for task A--directly comparable to how many times out of 100 you chose B). The only thing is that some people only decide whether to do A and C, while others only decide to do B or C.